# preg_match for one single digit number with a blank space on both sides

Tags: php, regex

I need to output the single 3 in the array below using preg_match or preg_split, how can I accomplish this? This possibilities are 1 through 8.

```
VMName Count CompatibilityForMigrationEnabled CompatibilityForOlderOperatingSystemsEnabled ------ ----- -------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- ap-1-38 3 False False
```

I have tried the following with no success using both preg_match and preg_split:

```
('\\s+\\d\\s+', $output)
('\\s+[\\d]\\s+', $output)
("^[\s0-9\s]+$", $output)
("/(.*), (.*)/", $output)
```

Comment: What exactly are the rules here?  Is there only ever one occurrence of a digit immediately preceded and followed by a space?  Is it always in the same spot or can it be anywhere?  You say "in the array below", but what you've provided is a string, not an array.  Which is it?

Comment: Tried `/( \d{1} )/`?

Comment: You should post your real code. And by the looks of it, you are missing the delimiters. And what's with the double backslashes?

Comment: Note that to match a `1` to `8` number that is in between whitespaces, you may use `preg_match('~(?<!\S)[1-8](?!\S)~', $s, $match)`.

Answer (score 2):

Give the following preg_match a try

```
<?php

$matched = preg_match('/( [0-9] )/', $string, $matches);
if($matched){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/( \d{1} )/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Examples:  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/luf

Answer (score 0):

To match a `1` to `8` number that is in between whitespaces, you may use

```
preg_match('~(?<!\S)[1-8](?!\S)~', $s, $match)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4z7vJ/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string required immediately to the left of the current location
- `[1-8]` - a digit from `1` to `8`
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string required immediately to the right of the current location

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9DU1MS):

```
$str = 'VMName Count CompatibilityForMigrationEnabled CompatibilityForOlderOperatingSystemsEnabled ------ ----- -------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- ap-1-38 3 False False';
if (preg_match('/(?<!\S)[1-8](?!\S)/', $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
// => 3
```

Note you may also use a capturing approach:

```
if (preg_match('/(?:^|\s)([1-8])(?:$|\s)/', $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4z7vJ/2) and the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/T6dOLy).

Here, `(?:^|\s)` is a non-capturing alternation group matching start of string *(`^`) or (`|`) a whitespace (`\s`), then a digit from `1` to `8` is captured (with `([1-8])`) and then `(?:$|\s)` matches the end of string (`$`) or a whitespace. `$match[1]` holds the necessary output.